# Изображения размываются сами

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть сайт (мобильная версия) [costascars.com/m/](http://costascars.com/m/)

Почему-то изображения выглядят размытыми (иконки языков в шапке, фото автомобиля ниже). Хотя, если открывать в браузере на компьютере (полный вид) или отдельно открывать изображения, то всё ОК. Что за фигня такая?

Comment: оно и в браузере размыто и сильно. Видимо передали чтобы быстрее грузилось для мобильных устройств.

Comment: Походу, это из-за указания размера в стилях. Было 60%, сделал полный размер - размытие убралось. Страннно, впервые сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой.